# Finding the number of points on the straight line joining $(-4,11)$ and $(16,-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems

Find the number of points on the straight line which joins $(-4,11)$ and $(16,-1)$ whose coordinates are positive integers.

a) $1$

b) $2$

c) $3$

d) $4$

Answer (score 7):

The slope of this line is $$\frac{-1-11}{16-(-4)}=\frac{-12}{20}=-\frac35\;.$$ Thus, the equation of the line is $y-11=-\frac35(x-(-4))=-\frac35x-\frac{12}5=-\frac15(3x+12)$. Clearly $y$ is an integer precisely when $3x+12$ is a multiple of $5$, which is the case precisely when $x+4$ is a multiple of $5$. These values of $x$ occur $5$ units apart, so between $-4$ and $16$ they are $-4,1,6,11$, and $16$, and the corresponding $y$-coordinates are $11,8,5,2$, and $-1$.

You don’t actually need the equation of the line. The slope of $-\frac35$ means that every $1$-unit increase in $x$ causes a decrease in $y$ of $\frac35$. Thus, it takes a $5$-unit increase in $x$ to decrease $y$ by an integer (namely, $3$), and the values of $x$ between $-4$ and $16$ that give integral values of $y$ must be $-4,1,6,11$, and $16$. The corresponding $y$-coordinates are $11,8,5,2$, and $-1$.

By either approach we see that the line segment contains exactly $3$ points whose coordinates are both positive integers.

Comment: Hi Brian, sorry to bother you again (currently studying for an exit exam and your posts/comments are always helpful) but I have a general question about the slope of a line: suppose that the slope of a line is $m = \frac{2}{3}$ given in units meters/seconds. Is saying "the rate of change is two meters per three seconds" equivalent to saying "the rate of change is two-thirds meters per second" by converting to a *unit rate*?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, it is. You can check by converting back: if an object is moving at a speed of ⅔ metres per second, then in $3$ seconds it travels $3\cdot\frac23=2$ metres. In other words, it travels two metres in each three-second interval, or two metres per three seconds.

Comment: That makes sense. So we can check that the rate $\frac{2}{3}$ meters per second is the same as the rate $2$ meters per $3$ seconds by observing that after $3$ seconds we will have travelled $2$ meters, *i.e.*, by seeing that $\frac{2}{3} \cdot 3 = 2$ meters?

Comment: additionally, as a follow up question: if we consider a curve (*i.e.,* the slope is not constant) instead of a line such that the derivative of the curve at a point is $\frac{2}{3}$ meters per second, could we still say that this is the same as "$2$ meters per $3$ seconds" at that point even though the rate of change may be different at a different point?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes to both questions. For the second one note that the instantaneous speed at a point is given by the slope of the tangent line at that point, irrespective of what happens at any other point, so you’re really still dealing with the case of constant slope.

Answer (score 5):

The equation of the line is $y-11=(\frac{11+1}{-4-16})(x+4)=-\frac{3}{5}(x+4)$. This means $3x+5y=43$.

Clearly $(1,8)$ is a point on the line such that $x$ and $y$ are both positive integers, and other such points are found by increasing $x$ by $5$ and decreasing $y$ by $3$. We then see that the only other such points are $(6,5)$ and $(11,2)$.

Comment: How did you find these solutions? Why aren't there more? This is an incomplete answer.

Comment: @akkkk: There’s nothing wrong with an incomplete answer that contains enough information to allow the details to be filled in reasonably easily, which was the case with Jasper’s original answer.

Comment: @akkkk: To find the first solution in cases like this, one can use Bezout's lemma (aka Bezout's identity).

Comment: @ShaneORourke: oh don't worry, I know how to find the answer, but clearly something's missing.

Answer (score 2):

The straight segment of line having those points as its extremes is

$$t(16,-1)+(1-t)(-4,11)=(20t-4\,,\,-12t+11)\,\,\,,\,\,0\leq t\leq 1$$

Well, it is plain that it must be that **both** $\,20t\,,\,12t\in\Bbb Z\,\,\,,\,\,t\in [0,1]$ , so

1) Prove that it *must be* $\,t\in\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]\,$

2) It also must be that, if $\,t=m/n\,$ , then $\,n\,\mid 20\,\,\,\text{and also }\,\,\,n\,\mid 12\,$ or else $\,m=0\,$

BTW, if we count the extreme points (and I don't understand why wouldn't we) , then the correct answer doesn't show up in the possible answers...

Comment: We don't care for the extreme points because last time I checked, $-4$ and $-1$ failed to be positive